# Best framework to create website that layman maintains

Tags: reactjs, angular, wordpress, web

I'm working with a friend who runs a small business in vehicle sales and would like to create a site for him that he maintains. I would design the layout, structure etc. and would want him to have the ability to add vehicles to the site without having to know too much about development. After creation I would only want to get involved if major changes are needed and they would add/remove vehicles on a daily basis.

Is something like Wordpress the only way to do this? Or are there better options available that give me the ability to make something that isn't a technical monstrosity that I can host for cheap? I'm experienced with most modern front-end web frameworks but have been out of the business for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am interpreting "best" to mean most easily maintainable.

If that's the case, your friend probably wants a low-code solution. Wordpress is an excellent option for blogging as a business or a CMS. Webflow is another, very powerful option, but it is a bit more code-intensive.

If your friend wants to process transactions though, he needs an ecommerce site. WooCommerce--a WordPress extension--and Shopify are both great options.